# Process: 11481 ExecStart=/sbin/afsd $AFSD_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Tags: 18.04

How can I fix this error on Ubuntu 18.04? It shows every time I updated and upgrade.
I don't know if I need openAFS.
Below is displayed on konsole.

```
● openafs-client.service - OpenAFS client
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openafs-client.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-12-26 14:06:00 GMT; 12ms ago
  Process: 11482 ExecStopPost=/sbin/rmmod $KMOD (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11481 ExecStart=/sbin/afsd $AFSD_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11473 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/openafs/openafs-client-precheck (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 26 14:06:00 gary-All-Series systemd[1]: Starting OpenAFS client...
Dec 26 14:06:00 gary-All-Series afsd[11481]: afsd: some file missing or bad in /etc/openafs/
Dec 26 14:06:00 gary-All-Series systemd[1]: openafs-client.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 26 14:06:00 gary-All-Series systemd[1]: openafs-client.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 26 14:06:00 gary-All-Series systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenAFS client.
dpkg: error processing package openafs-client (--configure):
 installed openafs-client package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openafs-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What version Ubuntu? What system?

Comment: Also, `Dec 26 14:06:00 gary-All-Series afsd[11481]: afsd: some file missing or bad in /etc/openafs/` is your indicator that a file it needs or a configuration item in there is bad.  Sounds like you need to go do some fixing there, or the package has bugs in it which need addressed for regular use.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at.

dpkg: error processing package openafs-client (--configure):
 installed openafs-client package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openafs-client

Checking out related answers to.

dpkg: error processing package openafs-client

Led me to.

sudo apt remove openafs-client

Then updated and upgraded.

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

On the Konsole I was prompted with.

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms openafs-modules-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.